# What is the difference between CPYF and CRTDUPOBJ in regard to a Physical/ Logical file?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

What is the difference when we use CPYF on a Pf/Lf and in case when we use command CRTDUPOBJ on PF/LF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPYF is focused on the data...

```
Replace or add records . . . . .   *NONE         *NONE, *ADD, *REPLACE... 
Create file  . . . . . . . . . .   *NO           *NO, *YES
Copy from record number  . . . .   *START        Number, *START 
Copy to record number  . . . . .   *END          Number, *END     
Copy from record key:                                             
  Number of key fields . . . . .   *NONE         Number, *BLDKEY  
  Key value  . . . . . . . . . .                                  
Copy to record key:                                               
  Number of key fields . . . . .   *NONE         Number, *BLDKEY  
  Key value  . . . . . . . . . .                                  
Number of records to copy  . . .   *END          Number, *END 
Include records by char test:                                              
  Field  . . . . . . . . . . . .   *NONE         Name, *NONE, *RCD, *FLD   
  Character position . . . . . .                 Number                    
  Relational operator  . . . . .                 *EQ, *GT, *LT, *NE, *GE...
  Value  . . . . . . . . . . . .                                           
Include records by field test:                                               
  Relationship . . . . . . . . .   *NONE         *NONE, *IF, *AND, *OR       
  Field  . . . . . . . . . . . .                 Name                        
  Relational operator  . . . . .                 *EQ, *GT, *LT, *NE, *GE...  
  Value  . . . . . . . . . . . .                                             
Record format field mapping  . .   *NONE         *NONE, *NOCHK, *CVTSRC...
```

CRTDUPOBJ focuses on the object as a whole

```
Duplicate data . . . . . . . . .   *NO    
Duplicate constraints  . . . . .   *YES   
Duplicate triggers . . . . . . .   *YES   
Duplicate file identifiers . . .   *NO    
Duplicate access control . . . .   *ALL
```